# Using relative path replace function to link to another language version of the same page

Tags: javascript, onclick, localization, internationalization, window.location

User should click on a link that points to another language version of the same page by rewriting the relative path.

I came up with the code below: Which works fine for the topleveldomain but I don't have a clue on how add /en/ just right after the domain by maintaining the rest of the url / link

example: like linking from domain.tld/folder/thispage.html to domain.tld/EN/folder/thispage.html

```
<li class="language"><a id="changelanguage" href="#" onclick="window.location = window.location.href.replace('bezahlte--umfragen.de/', 'bezahlte--umfragen.de/en/')">Change Language</a></li>
```

my site structure:
german version: domain.tld/index.php (domain.tld/contentfolder/)
english version: domain.tld/en/index.php (domain.tld/en/contentfolder/

Comment: This is a general Internationalisation problem. Searched for I18n may be helpful to you.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I have tried searching for I18n but the results confuse me even more. Isn't my goal as simple as I thought?

Comment: Regrettably, it is pretty difficult to do it well.

You might want to look at "content negotiation" and "accept language http headers"

Comment: "Content negotiation refers to mechanisms defined as a part of HTTP that make it possible to serve different versions of a document at the same URI"

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Actually I dont want to do that. I just want to point the user to another subfolder. For example: The user enters the german version of the website, clicks on the change language button, chooses english and gets redirected from [www.bezahlte-umfragen.de/tipps/](http://www.bezahlte-umfragen.de/tipps/) to [www.bezahlte-umfragen.de/en/tipps/](http://www.bezahlte-umfragen.de/en/tipps/).

Im looking for some piece of code that does that automatically by using the relative path of the doc and adding /en/